# Node in linked list not being deleted properly?

Tags: c, linked-list, singly-linked-list

I have posted MCVE code which can be copied and run in any IDE to check the results.

The input in the linked list is as follows:

```
Kevlar Epoxy 43.75 18.90 1.48 0.34 0.148 3.93
Kevlar Polycarbonate 43.40 14.00 1.39 0.34 0.110 2.75
Kevlar ABS 43.42 13.94 1.35 0.35 0.112 2.74
```

The result I am looking for is:

```
Kevlar Epoxy 43.75 18.90 1.48 0.34 0.148 3.93
Kevlar ABS 43.42 13.94 1.35 0.35 0.112 2.74
```

The result I am getting is:

```
Kevlar Epoxy 43.75 18.90 1.48 0.34 0.148 3.93
Some random symbols 43.40 14.00 1.39 0.34 0.110 2.75
Kevlar ABS 43.42 13.94 1.35 0.35 0.112 2.74
```

In this problem I am trying to delete the intermediate node, therefore I am not considering the first and last node. Please can someone let me know why is this happening?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

struct lamina
{
  char lamina_fiber[30];
  char lamina_matrix[30];
  float E1,E2,p,v12,v21,G12;
  struct lamina *nextnode;
};

 int main()
{
  struct lamina *head,*data;
  head=(struct lamina *)calloc(1,sizeof(struct lamina));
  data=head;

 strcpy(data->lamina_fiber,"Kevlar");
 strcpy(data->lamina_matrix,"Epoxy");
 data->E1= 43.75;
 data->E2= 18.90;
 data->p= 1.48;
 data->v12= 0.34;
 data->v21= 0.148;
 data->G12= 3.93;

 data->nextnode=(struct lamina *)calloc(1,sizeof(struct lamina));
 data=data->nextnode;

 strcpy(data->lamina_fiber,"Kevlar");
 strcpy(data->lamina_matrix,"Polycarbonate");
 data->E1= 43.40;
 data->E2= 14.00;
 data->p= 1.39;
 data->v12= 0.34;
 data->v21= 0.110;
 data->G12= 2.75;

 data->nextnode=(struct lamina *)calloc(1,sizeof(struct lamina));
 data=data->nextnode;     

strcpy(data->lamina_fiber,"Kevlar");
strcpy(data->lamina_matrix,"ABS");
data->E1= 43.42;
data->E2= 13.94;
data->p= 1.35;
data->v12= 0.35;
data->v21= 0.112;
data->G12= 2.74;

data=head;

struct lamina *temp,*anothertemp;
temp=(struct lamina *)calloc(1,sizeof(struct lamina));
anothertemp=(struct lamina *)calloc(1,sizeof(struct lamina));

temp=data;
size_t i=0;

while(i<1)
{    
 temp=temp->nextnode; 
 i++;
}

if(i==1)
{
 anothertemp=temp->nextnode;
 anothertemp=temp;
 free(temp); 
}

  for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
   {
      printf("%s %s %5.2f %5.2f %5.2f %5.2f %5.2f %5.2f\n",
      data->lamina_fiber,data->lamina_matrix,data->E1,data->E2,data->p, 
      data->v12,data->v21,data->G12);
      data=data->nextnode;
   }

}
```

Comment: OT: regarding statements like: `data->E1= 43.75;`  the literal: `43.75` is a `double` but the destination field is a `float`  To correct this problem, append a `f` after all those literals

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
strcpy(data->lamina_fiber,"Kevlar");
strcpy(data->lamina_fiber,"Polycarbonate");
```

should be

```
strcpy(data->lamina_fiber,"Kevlar");
strcpy(data->lamina_matrix,"Polycarbonate");
```

Otherwise you are printing uninitialized memory (which is the reason for your "Some Random Symbols")

Furthermore, if you are trying to delete the second node, you have to modify the first node (head):

```
head->next = head->next->next;
```

To free the deleted node, first save `head->next` to a temporary variable and free it at last.

Comment: Sorry that was a typo, I edited that, thanks for point it out though.

Comment: anothertemp=temp->nextnode is basically head->next = head->next->next ?

Comment: @AMD No, an assignment to `anothertemp` does not modify the head of your list at all.

Comment: I am assigning the last node, the value of nextnode in the first node right?

Comment: For example this: `anothertemp=temp->nextnode; anothertemp=temp;` is always wrong, you are just assigning two different pointers to `anothertemp` which you don't use at all. You only _assign_ to `anothertemp` and _never_ read from it.

Comment: After my while loop ends, temp is the value of the nextnode in the first node, than I assign anothertemp the value of the last node and after I assign the last node the value of the nextnode in first node. Pointing the first node to the last node to skip the one in between, that is the objective right?

Comment: @AMD It is key that you try to understand, that `anothertemp` is only written to and never used/read. You can eliminate anothertemp completely, it will change nothing.

Comment: Thank You, for pointing out the mistake, so what should I do to read from it?

Comment: @AMD yes, that's what `head->next = head->next->next` does. In general: Iterate to the node _before_ the node to delete, and do `node->next = node->next->next`(but remember to save the pointer to free it after the assignment)

Comment: If the `->next->next` soup gives you heartache, you can always just save a `prev` pointer to bracket the nodes, e.g. `prev, node_to_del, next`. It's up to you. Key is to draw it out on paper, erase the `node_to_del` and then code what you must do to connect the `prev->next` pointer to `next`.